Подключение анимаций 3D модели в ursina engine
как воспроизвести анимацию 3D модели в ursina engine скажем в 3D модели PistolBetta есть анимация  Fire которую необходимо воспроизвести в игре, как это реалезовать?
1 вариант кода
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()
Sky()
from ursina import *

window.color = color._20

animation = Animation('PistolBetta\Fire', fps=2, scale=1, filtering=None, autoplay=True)

app.run()
EditorCamera()

2 вариант кода
from ursina import *
from direct.actor.Actor import Actor
app = Ursina()
Sky()
entity = Entity()
actor = Actor('PistolBetta')
actor.reparent_to(entity)
actor.loop('Fire')
EditorCamera()

3 вариант
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
Sky()
gun = FrameAnimation3d ('PistolBetta\idle', fps = 20, loop = True, autoplay= True)
EditorCamera()

4 варик
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
Sky()
gun = Entity (model = ("PistolBetta"))
EditorCamera()
gun = Sequence (1, Func(gun.idle, duration = 1), loop = True)

5 вариант
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
Sky()
model = Entity(model="PistolBetta", collider="mesh", position=(-2, -9.5, 0), flipped_faces=False, double_sided=True,animations=[Animation('PistolBetta\idle', 1, 24)])

model.animation_speed = 2
model.animate('PistolBetta\idle', 1, loop=True)
EditorCamera()
def input (key):
    if key == 'escape':
        application.quit()

app.run()

ни один нормально не работает, как правило скрипты тупо не запускаются
